# Writing to network share failed

Tags: windows-server-2003, outlook

I have outlook files stored on a network share and accessed by clients directly.
Outlook is version 2003, clients windows XP and server is 2003.
The files are quite big at around 3GB.

One of the common problem that happens is that I get 'delayed write failed' and this happens only on these PST files.

When this happens I have to run scanpst.exe to fix the PST file.
I did not find any entries in even logs that I could relate to the issue.

What would you suggest to change to fix the issue or where to look to further diagnose it?

EDIT:
No loss on ping and ping times within normal for LAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that this is a great answer but Microsoft definitely doesn't support PST over LAN.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297019

Comment: No, that is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is true that pst files are not supported over a Lan, I understand your pain. I have had delayed write failed errors on my network shares as well, most of the time when  transferring big files (about 20 gigs). I suggest you check your disk configuration on the server. There are many leads . Check this http://www.gibni.com/windows-delayed-write-failed-solutions. In my case it was a network card settings (had to update the driver). But I had another instance when the disk I was writing to was faulty and had to be replaced, after which the delayed write failed errors stopped.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers - I will follow up on the storage issues, too.